# Max on pandas (sql style) between column and number

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

The following is very easy on SQL but I cannot figure out on Pandas.

```
In [7]: import pandas as pd

In [8]: table = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1, 2], ['b', 4,5], ['c', 7,2]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

In [10]: table['d'] = None

In [11]: table
Out[11]:
   a  b  c     d
0  a  1  2  None
1  b  4  5  None
2  c  7  2  None
```

On SQL I could do:

```
UPDATE Table SET d = max(10, b, c)
```

On pandas I know I can do:

```
table.loc[:, 'd'] = table[['b', 'c']].max(axis=1)
```

But I have no idea on how to add a fixed number (the 10 on my SQL example).

My only idea so far was to somehow create a new DF with the 10 and then do the max of that but it looks a little cumbersome! (a simple `Column C = Min(Max(10, Column B), 100)` [ C = 10 < B < 100] becomes 3 different DF put together!).

Comment: Sorry are you trying to do `10 + table[['b','c']].max(axis=1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to make a temporary column with the value 10, or assign 10 to the 'd' column and then overwrite it:

```
In [60]: table['d'] = 10

In [61]: table['d'] = table[['b', 'c', 'd']].max(axis=1)
```

Another option with which it will be more easily to do more complex operations (but note that this will be less performant if you are dealing with large tables!):

```
In [72]: table['d'] = table.apply(lambda x: max(5, x['b'], x['c']), axis=1)
```

---

Using numpy's `maximum` function, you can do such elementwise max calculations (but only between 2 arguments at once):

```
In [73]: np.maximum(table['b'], table['c'])
Out[73]:
0    2
1    5
2    7
Name: b, dtype: int64

In [74]: np.maximum(table['b'], 10)
Out[74]:
0    10
1    10
2    10
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

Comment: thanks so much! I tested the lambda solution and it is very slow (for 150,000 rows it took 20s). The 3rd method however is great `np.minimum(np.maximum(df['a'], 1), 2)` takes less that a sec to run on the same amount of data.